# linux csv column with multiple comma separators - sed regex match and replace with quotes

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed

It's bit of tough, trying to hack the solution.

One of the column from exported sql table as csv has bit of strings separated by commas, data kind of below. Some rows have only strings without any delimiter but others like below -

###### Requirement to double quote whole string by matching regex

```
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1
```

##### Here, what i am stuck at

Sample of file looks like

```
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,800,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1,4,0,28169.8,0,NULL,0.0604592,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0.666667,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1703.12,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,250,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1,4,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,99.9459,3.88318,0,NULL,25.7521,0.666667,888,50848,43,1966,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,340,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1,6,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,100,100,0.000163336,NULL,0.0388318,1,43,1966,888,50848,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
```

Below format is endgoal - the complete string is double quoted. Grep by regex and add double quotes at both ends.
below example - trying initially by regex and apply sed,

```
grep -Eo "\w{10}\=\w{12},\w{10}=\w{3}.*,\w{10}=[[:alnum:]]" export.csv | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/'
"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1"
"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1"
"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1"
```

But, by grep and using sed -i, it doesn't modify inplace matched regex -

for ex -

```
tail export.csv | sed -e 's/"\w{10}\=\w{12},\w{10}=\w{3}.*,\w{10}=\d$"/"/;s/$/"/'
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,800,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1,4,0,28169.8,0,NULL,0.0604592,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0.666667,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1703.12,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK"
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,250,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1,4,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,99.9459,3.88318,0,NULL,25.7521,0.666667,888,50848,43,1966,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK"
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,340,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1,6,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,100,100,0.000163336,NULL,0.0388318,1,43,1966,888,50848,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK"
```

is only adding " at the end of row of the **last column.**

Comment: Don't try to parse csv files using `sed` or `awk` as there are parsers written that handle many edge cases. You might try [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), [GoCSV](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv) or the perl module Text::CSV.

Comment: This is not a hard problem. Use `awk -F,` and be done with it, e.g. `awk -F, '{print "\""$1"\""', "\""$2"\""}`

Comment: `sed -e 's/"\w{10}\=\w{12},\w{10}=\w{3}.*,\w{10}=\d$"/"/;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' export.csv` If this is what you want, append `-i` carefully.

Comment: its not working, you are assuming only one column, there are other columns with other data.

Comment: Please update your question with other columns and include the exact desired outputs.

Comment: @ConstantinHong - sure, done now.

Comment: So is your question "how to double quotes from col 12 to col 19 in csv"?

Comment: How was this data exported? It is a bit surprising that the database engine did not produce quoted CSV output, as it was supposed to.

Comment: You made your question less clear and more confusing by sometime showing a full line and other times just showing the "field" you want to quote from the line. Always showing the full line would have been clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point is to put quotes around sequences of `\w+=\w+`-matching `,`-separated fields, with `perl`:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/(?<![^,])(\w+=\w+)(,(?1))*(?![^,])/"$&"/g' your-file
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,800,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1",AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,"AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",4,0,28169.8,0,NULL,0.0604592,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0.666667,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1703.12,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,250,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1",AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,"AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",4,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,99.9459,3.88318,0,NULL,25.7521,0.666667,888,50848,43,1966,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,340,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1",AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,"AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",6,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,100,100,0.000163336,NULL,0.0388318,1,43,1966,888,50848,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
```

Note how `AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD` is out of the quotes as `-` is not a `\w`ord character. Replace `\w` with `[\w-]` or `[^,"=]` to match on any character other than `,`, `"` and `=` for instance for it to be included.

Add the `-i` option to modify your file `i`n-place.

Comment: man, many thanks ... you just saved my day,...  apart from perl, do you think this can be achieved by sed !

Comment: @Indranil, that can be achieved more or less easily and generally less reliably depending on the `sed` implementation, but why would you want to use `sed`?

Comment: its just a personal preference, having being all time with awk and sed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```bash
$ awk '{ sub(/[_[:alpha:]]{10}=[_[:alpha:]]{12},[_[:alpha:]]{10}=[_[:alpha:]]{3}.*,[_[:alpha:]]{10}=[[:alnum:]]+/, "\"&\"")}1'

# Using GNU awk
$ awk '{sub(/\w{10}=\w{12},\w{10}=\w{3}.*,\w{10}=[[:alnum:]]{1,}/, "\"&\"" ) }1'
```

Or using `GNU awk`'s `gensub()` function

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(^.*)(\w{10}=\w{12},\w{10}=\w{3}.*,\w{10}=[[:alnum:]]{1,})(.*$)/, "\\1\"\\2\"\\3", "g"); }'
```

Comment: thanks, but you are filtering out, i need to put back the matched and quoted line back to same file.

Comment: yes, it works now -- thankyou very much...

 awk -v q=\" '{sub(/\w{10}=\w{12},\w{10}=\w{3}.*,\w{10}=[[:alnum:]]{1,}/, q "&" q ) }1' export.csv

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$12="\""$12; $19=$19"\""} 1' file
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,800,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",4,0,28169.8,0,NULL,0.0604592,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0.666667,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1703.12,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,250,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",4,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,99.9459,3.88318,0,NULL,25.7521,0.666667,888,50848,43,1966,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,340,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",6,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,100,100,0.000163336,NULL,0.0388318,1,43,1966,888,50848,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
```

or a sed with `-E` to enable EREs, e.g. GNU or BSD sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){11})(([^,]*,){7}[^,]*)/\1"\3"/' file
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,800,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L2-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",4,0,28169.8,0,NULL,0.0604592,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0.666667,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1703.12,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,250,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L3-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",4,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,99.9459,3.88318,0,NULL,25.7521,0.666667,888,50848,43,1966,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
export_pl,XYSS04S,58.38,340,39544,0,6,NULL,NULL,0,0,"SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_AB,SubNetwork=XYZ,MeContext=XYSS04S,ManagedElement=XYSS04S,Equipment=1,AntennaUnitGroup=L1-TDD,AntennaNearUnit=1,RetSubUnit=1",6,0,28169.8,0,0,NULL,NULL,100,100,0.000163336,NULL,0.0388318,1,43,1966,888,50848,NULL,NULL,NULL,RT,2023-10-08 00:00:00,2023-10-10 00:00:00,20:00:00;21:00:00;22:00:00;14:00:00,1,OK
```

Comment: +1. `$12="\""$12` is simpler and beautiful.